# How does hibernate manage concurrent access

Tags: java, oracle, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency

I have an application that uses two threads to do the following

1. get a record from the db- for this query I use a `select .. for update`
2. update a field of the record/object in Java
3. save the updated object.

   ```
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public Records getRecordCondition() {
       Record record = recordDAO.findRecord(5);
       recordDAO.updateRecordStatus(record);
       return record;
   }
   // In Dao Class
   public Record findRecord(int number) {
       Session session = getCurrentSession();
       try {
           String sql =
                   "from record r where r.id =:recordId";
           Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
           query.setLockMode("r", LockMode.UPGRADE);
           query.setString("recordId", number);
           return query.uniqueResult();
   ```

However, when I run the application, I see both threads selecting the same object and updating it. (I used logs to see what each thread is doing). In my service class I use the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. The above three steps are executed from the service class calling 2 different methods. The get record and the save record. The select for update does lock the record for the duration of the transaction. In the DAO I do `sessionFactory.getSession()` to get a session for each call to the db. I am struggling to understand why thread 2 is able to get the record that thread 1 is already processing, it should be locked. Is it possible that the threads are using the same connection? What is the difference between a connection and a session? Can two threads end up sharing the same session?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, and also specify the database system you use. These types of locks are usually enforced through the DBMS.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using oracle a db

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.